# Highcharts $.ajax API

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts, area

I want to make a dynamic schedule update via the API. The value "total" should be displayed on the graph. I tried using PHP, but the values are not entered on the graph. Help me fix and understand what my mistake is.

````
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.vimeworld.com',
    data: {data: day},
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
    })
    
    };
        ```

And here is my PHP code that should send a request to the server API and return a value.
````

````
<?php
    function getApiData($param) {
    $curl = curl_init("https://api.vimeworld.com/online");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Access-Token: DMjJuuybMHXXt3KH1LkAB1HQdQZnfoR' // Примерный вид токена, тебе надо использовать свой
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($param));
    }
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
    }
?>```
Thank you in advance for your help and assistance.
````

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database) from documentation on how to work with data.